# Solving XSS issues

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-4, xss, sql-injection

I am trying to build an MVC application and have been told it is not a good way to retrieve data and is susceptible to cross-site scripting. I have never done security and have been trying to learn as well but I cannot wrap my head around it.

I am guessing there are several flaws here. Is there any particular encoding I can use?

I haven't pasted the entire code here but trying to figure out where I can stop the XSS attacks.

Model and View Model

```
namespace ThePeopleSearchApplication.Models
{
    public class UserViewModel
    {
        public string UID{ get; set; }
        public string FName{ get; set; }
        public string LName{ get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Status{ get; set; }

    }

    public class UserModel
    {
        public string UID{ get; set; }
        public string FName{ get; set; }
        public string LName{ get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Status{ get; set; }
    }

}
```

Controller

```
    namespace ThePeopleSearchApplication.Controllers
{
    public class MyController : Controller
    {
        // GET: My
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ValidateInput(false)] //has been added to understand XSS better
        public ActionResult SearchUserAjax(string userId)
        {
            UserModel myUser = fetchUserFromLdap(userId);
            return Content("{\"message\": \"search for userId: " +
                           userId + " result\", \"result\": " + convertToJson(myUser) + " }");
        }

        private string convertToJson(UserModel myUser)
        {
            return "{ \"userId\": \"" + myUser.UserId + "\", \"FirstName\": \"" +
                   myUser.FirstName + "\", \"LastName\": \"" + myUser.LastName + "\", \"Email\": \"" +
                   myUser.Email + "\", \"Status\": \"" + myUser.Status + "\"}";
        }

        [ValidateInput(false)] //has been added to understand XSS better
        public ActionResult SearchUser(string userId)
        {
            UserModel myUser = fetchUserFromLdap(userId);
            var viewModel = new UserViewModel
            {
                UID = userId,
                FName = myUser.FirstName,
                LName = myUser.LastName,
                Email = myUser.Email,
                Status = myUser.Status,
            };
            return this.View(viewModel);
        }

        private UserModel fetchUserFromLdap(string userId)
        {
            var retVal = new UserModel();
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
            {
                retVal.UID = "N/A";
                retVal.FName = "N/A";
                retVal.LName = "N/A";
                retVal.Email = "N/A";
                retVal.Status = "N/A";
            }
            else
            {
                retVal.UID = userId;
                retVal.FName = "FirstName";
                retVal.LName = "LastName";
                retVal.Email = "email@example.com";
                retVal.Status = "<div style=background-color:#F00800>My Status</div>";
            }

            return retVal;

        }
    }
}
```

View

```
    @model ThePeopleSearchApplication.Models.UserViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Search result for user: " + Model.UserId;
    var ulId = "ul-id" + Model.UserId;
    var formId = "form" + Model.UserId;
}
<html>
<head>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
</head>
<body>
<h1>Search result for user: @Model.UserId</h1>
<ul id="@Html.Raw(ulId)">
    <li>@Model.FirstName</li>
    <li>@Model.LastName</li>
    <li>@Model.Email</li>
    <li>@Html.Raw(Model.Status)</li>
</ul>
<form id=@formId name=@formId action=/My/SearchUser enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="userId" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var theForm = document.@formId;
    $(theForm).submit(function() {
        alert('Valid form');
        return true;
    });
// just to demonstrate potential usage $(theForm).submit();
</script>
<div>
    Ajax search:
    <form id="ajax-search" name="ajax-search">
        <input type="text" name="userId" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    <script>
        $("#ajax-search").submit(function() {
            var url = "/My/SearchUserAjax"; // the script where you handle the form input.
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $("#ajax-search").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                success: function(data)
                {
                    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                    $('#ajax-search').append('<hr/>');
                    $('#ajax-search').append(obj.message); // show response from the php script.
                    $('#ajax-search').append('<hr/>');
                    $('#ajax-search').append(obj.result.userId);
                    $('#ajax-search').append('<hr/>');
                    $('#ajax-search').append(obj.result.FirstName);
                    $('#ajax-search').append('<hr/>');
                    $('#ajax-search').append(obj.result.LastName);
                    $('#ajax-search').append('<hr/>');
                    $('#ajax-search').append(obj.result.Status);
                    $('#ajax-search').append('<hr/>');
                }
            });
            return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
        });
    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was able to get some more details but still, not complete. trying to use the scanner in VS 2017  https://security-code-scan.github.io/#SCS0029

Answer (score 0):

The principle problem is if the User controls some data that you render to the page in an unsafe way. Whether that be from their name (my name is `<script>function() { nasty stuff is happening here... }</script>`) or any other content.

I take the following approach, look at your output (or better think ahead about it) and see if it's a problem at each stage:

1. Let Razor do it, by default Razor handles encoding of all HTML
   characters on the page, this doesn't apply if you use an
   `IHtmlString` so avoid this `Type` (or methods that return it like
   `Html.Raw()`) so `@("<script>nastyThings()</script>")` is a `string` so that will be encoded, and the script will not run
2. If it's broken, that means your string has some HTML/JS in it that
   you actually want to render. So try and move that directly onto the
   Razor template (HTML/JS) or obtain it via a link (JS)

   - Instead of the whole `string` being user controlled `"<element onclick="javascript:alert('trouble')"></element>"` with template `@Html.Raw(Model.UserBadString)`
   - Make the template `<element onclick="mySafeJsFunction()">@Model.UserSafeString</element>`", this takes control of the JS function away from the User, and leaves them with a Razor encoded parameter that they can't do XSS with
3. You want the User to have control over the HTML, then you will have to sanitise the string on output to the page, by using something like (https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer)

   - So the template could be `@Html.Raw(sanitizer.Sanitize(Model.UserBadString))` but you'd probably want to do something nicer than that, good coding practice etc. The main point is that the `string` is sanitised

As an aside, make sure you keep a very close aye on usages of properties such as `.innerHTML` in JS (or the dreaded jQuery `.html()` which calls `eval()`), as if these take in user controlled content you'll have the exact same problem. But the same steps can be applied, (1) use `.innerText` instead, or (3) otherwise use a purification library on the string like DOMPurify before giving it to the JS (https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify). Unfortunately in this case option (2) is not recommended, since whatever is left will have to be made safe by you or I, I'd rather trust DOMPurify to do it :)